# Non-Abelian Group whose sum of subgroups becomes a subgroup

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $A, B$ be a subgroup of $G$. We define $AB$={$ab \in G: a \in A \land b \in B$} the sum of $A$ and $B$. My textbook asserts that $AB=BA \iff AB$ is also a subgroup of $G$. This implies that if G is Abelian, for any $A,B$: subgroups of $G$, $AB$ becomes a subgroup of $G$.

My question is, is there any non-Abelian group with this property? i.e. for any two subgroups $A, B$ of $G$, $AB$ is also a subgroup of $G$. What I know is that any non-Abelian group has at least 6 elements, so it was too difficult for me to make a counter-example. The simplest non-Abelian group, dihedral group $D_3$, fails to have this property so I'm a bit skeptical about this. On the other hand, I couldn't prove that any non-Abelian group shouldn't have this property at the moment. Any counter-example or simple proof of this assertion could be possible?

Might be a simple problem but a bit of help would be greatly thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the groups in which every subgroup is permutable. For instance, the non-abelian group of order $p^{3}$ and exponent $p^{2}$, where $p$ is an odd prime, does satisfy this condition, although not all of its subgroups are normal.

---

See [this paper](http://www.dma.unina.it/~degiovan/Pubblicazioni/111.pdf) for references.

Comment: That's quite interesting. It seems not be the necessary condition though since the quaternion group (order 8) has this property as mesel has pointed out. Also thanks for the reference: I'll definitely check it after I've got more familiar with group theory.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there are some nonabelian groups in which every proper subgroup is normal. These groups satisfies this property as $$N_1.N_2=N_2.N_1$$

For normal groups $N_1$ and $N_2$. The smallest example is [$Q_8$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group)  the quaternion group.

Comment: So in this case every subgroup becomes normal hence permutable, right? Thanks for the simple answer: I was also wondering the smallest possible such nonabelian group.

Comment: @TaxxiDriver: You are welcome. $Q_8$ is the smallest one.